# Regular matrix and regular stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

We know that :

1. A matrix is regular if its determinant is non zero.
2. A stochastic matrix is regular if at a certain power all elements are positive.

Question is how can I make the link between the two definitions, if there are any ? thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a link, and have never heard the term regular to denote invertible matrices.

Comment: @user139388 : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonsingularMatrix.html

Comment: I see, perhaps it is an outdated term. In any case, you are asking about a connection between the invertibility of a matrix vs the irreducibility of a Markov kernel, but I'm not sure what connection exists. Note that it is easy to construct non-invertible kernels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this matrix \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}The first power itself has all elements positive, it is doubly stochastic and still has a zero determinant.