# Sum of regular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This question is asked in **Topics in Algebra** by **I N Herstein**-
*If the field $\displaystyle F$ has an infinite number of elements then prove that every element in $\displaystyle F_{n}$ can be written as a sum of regular matrices.*

$\displaystyle F_{n}$ is the set of all $\displaystyle n\times n$ matrices over $\displaystyle F$.

I am thinking if I prove that a matrix can be written as a sum of two invertible matrices then this will prove this question.

Is this the correct way to prove this question? If not, then how can I prove that **a matrix can be written as a sum of regular matrices?**

Comment: Kindly define a "regular" matrix.

Comment: [link text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_matrix)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202533/show-any-matrix-a-n-times-n-can-be-written-as-sum-of-two-nonsingular-matrice should be a duplicate (not exactly, because regular matrices could constitute a larger set than invertible matrices, but it does answer the question).

Comment: No, my question is if a matrix can be written as a sum of regular matrices.

Comment: Yes, but invertible matrices are regular, and you can write any matrix as the sum of two invertible matrices, so you can write anything as the sum of two regular matrices. Look, if all invertible matrices are not regular, then the link you've sent me is not helpful enough. I need you to type in the definition of a regular matrix in the case that invertible matrices are not regular.

Comment: [](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729835/is-a-regular-stochastic-matrix-definitely-nonsingular) I am not sure if all the invertible matrices are regular. And there is no specific definition of regular matrix in this chapter of the book so I have only one source that I have shared already.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802260/regular-matrix-and-regular-stochastic-matrix?rq=1 Here is an example of a matrix that is regular stochastic but its determinant is zero.